# How does one know if a project is using Webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I started from this : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

I'm not sure if it uses Webpack or not.

What files would a project containing/using webpack contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is using Webpack then there will be a `webpack.config.js` file in the root of the project.

Edit: I guess `webpack.config.js` is no longer necessary. So you *could* look at the package.json and see if webpack is a dependency.

Comment: does not having that but having `build/webpack.base.conf.js` and other "conf" files count?

Comment: If you run `webpack` at the root of your project that will also give you a clue. But I'm pretty sure it requires a config at the project root.

Comment: weird. I have all the webpack files that clearly interact with the project (editing them can cause npm run to fail) yet running `webpack` states no config file was found. can you please take a look at the scaffolding I linked and tell me how I'm to configure webpack for it?

Comment: This is just not true. Webpack 4 does not strictly require any config files at all. see: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-tutorial/